# How to call dynamicly string operations in Python?

Tags: python

```
//func_to_exec parameter is coming from database dynamically.
func_to_exec='split("\|")[0].split(",")[1]'

pl='mancity,manunited,arsenal|2|3|4|5'
```

is there anyway to call

```
pl.func_to_exec
```

I saw exec and eval functions are only for integers. I cant find any solution for strings.
Thx for suggestions.

Comment: Where did you see that exec and eval are only for integers?

Comment: examples for integers only, i tried many times but not working.

Comment: I really hope this isn't some remote database, otherwise you open a big breach in your security by executing externally provided code. Somebody can reverse engineer your system and delete/acquire your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exec function for that:

```
pl = 'mancity,manunited,arsenal|2|3|4|5'
func_to_exec = 'split("\|")[0].split(",")[1]'

exec(f'result = pl.{func_to_exec}')
print(result)  # Output: 'manunited'
```

Comment: And yes, as someone said above, better to avoid using exec and eval whenever possible, as they can be vulnerable to injection attacks

Comment: i know, its not remote db and its console app. And its works! Thank you for your suggestion. Regards